# Как вывести в Laravel через route определённые ссылки

Tags: php, laravel, маршрутизация, route, sitemap

Вопрос, как вывести в Laravel через route ссылки, в которых имеются значения допустим naprimer? (Делаю для последовательной карты сайта)

```
<loc>https://site.by/<?php echo e($gener->route), false); ?></loc>
```

Comment: Почему бы не использовать [уже готовый пакет](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap)?

Answer (score 1):

К примеру есть сущность Post  и роут на просмотр постов

```php
#routes/web.php
Route::get('posts/{slug}', 'PostController@show')->name('posts.show');
```

Добавим роут для sitemap:

```php
#routes/web.php
Route::get('sitemap.xml', 'PostController@sitemap')->name('sitemap');
```

И метод sitemap В PostController

```php
    public function sitemap()
    {           
        return Response::view('sitemap', ['posts' => Post::all()])
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    }
```

А в blade шаблоне sitemap будет;

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <url>
            <loc>{{ route('posts.show', $post->slug) }}</loc>
        </url>
    @endforeach
</urlset>
```